# How to upload file along with json meta data using rest api

Tags: file, upload, multipartform-data

I have requirement to upload xlsx file on server along with some json data(both has to be done in one request). I was able to upload just file using multipart/form-data, but when I tried add JSON data to the same request, request is failing with **org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream**

exception. Below is my code.

Client side code

```
var method = 'POST';
 $.ajax({
         type: method,
         url : "rest/file/upload",
         transformRequest: function () {
             var formData = new FormData();
             formData.append("model", JSON.stringify(jsonData));                        
             formData.append("file",document.getElementById("fileForm"));
             return formData;
            },
           enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
           processData : false,
           contentType : false,
           success: function (data) {},
              error: function (data) {}
         });
```

model is the JSON data & file is xlsx file which is to be uploaded.
Server Side Code

```
  @POST
        @Path("/upload")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public Response uploadResumableISOFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context UriInfo uri,
                @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            ServletFileUpload uploader = null;
            try {
                DiskFileItemFactory fileFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                uploader = new ServletFileUpload(fileFactory);
                List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator<FileItem> fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator();
                while (fileItemsIterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem fileItem = fileItemsIterator.next();
                    File file = File.createTempFile("TEMP_", ".xlsx");
                    fileItem.write(file);
                    System.out.print("File " + fileItem.getName() + " uploaded successfully.");
                }
                System.out.println("File uploaded to successfully...");
                return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Failed to upload file.").build();
            }
        }


Please let me know if something is missing.
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this myself but the requests are not being sent like they should be. Tried with postman but there is no option available to specify multiple content types (for each part). Did you find out how to do this?